# MSBuild fails on VB.NET lambda expressions

Tags: .net, vb.net, msbuild-4.0

I have an issue with building a project using the [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) (ver 4) from the command line
when declaring lambda expression like this:

```
Private Sub Foo(ByVal s As String)
    Dim WL = Sub(str As String)
                 If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) Then
                     Console.WriteLine(str)
                 End If
             End Sub
    WL(s)
End Sub
```

The error occurs at second line of code above:

> **error BC30201: Expression expected.**

In Visual Studio 2010 it compiles just fine.

MSBuild BAT file:

```
SET MSBUILD="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
SET LogDll="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.Engine.Dll"

SET VSBuildSolName="d:\Projects\Source\Test.sln"

SET VSBuildConfigNameD="Debug"
SET VSBuildConfigNameR="Release"

SET VSBuildErrFileNameD="d:\Projects\build\Test_errD.txt"
SET VSBuildErrFileNameR="d:\Projects\build\Test_errR.txt"

CALL %MSBUILD% %VSBuildSolName% /p:Configuration=%VSBuildConfigNameD% /logger:FileLogger,%LogDll%;LogFile=%VSBuildErrFileNameD% /verbosity:normal /P:NOWARN= /tv:3.5
```

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with project/solution settings (the project was migrated from .net 2.0 to .net 3.5)
Сurrent project's settings:
`Option strict: Off
Option infer: On`

I just have checked the issue for new test solution from scratch and there are no errors.

Comment: It seems the reason is the version of VB.NET. Only VB.NET 2010 (.net 4.0) supports such (multiple statements) expressions.

Comment: You can add what you have discovered as an answer, its ok to answer your own question on SO.

Comment: Due to the [What’s New in Visual Basic 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336123.aspx) "multi-line Sub lambdas" is the new feature of the Visual Basic 2010 and it can be the answer why MsBuild 4 doesn't build from the command line my migrated from .net 2.0 to .net 3.5 project. 
But I haven't found the answers to these questions: 
1) why Visual Studio 2010 builds it without errors?
2) why when I created new project in VS 2010 from scratch with target framework .net 3.5 for testing this issue, all: MsBuild 3.5, MsBuild 4 and Visual Studio 2010 builds it without errors?

Comment: Diff the project file that works with the one that doesn't work.  They are just XML files and you might discover something.

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to your question

> 1) why Visual Studio 2010 builds it without errors?

It is of course possible to write code in each subsequent version of Visual Studio that will not work in earlier versions especially when such code uses new features of the current version or current IDE of Visual Studio or the Express Edition.

Take for example a one line PROPERTY, you can not do that in previous versions of VB.Net prior to 2010, as another example, you can not omit the line continuation character in versions prior to 2010 where you can in 2010 in certain parts of your code.